# Segmentation Fault when Modifying a cJSON Struct Created by Parsing a String Literal

Tags: c, cjson

When using cJSON to parse a string literal I was getting a segmentation fault when free'ing the cJSON structure.

The original code was as follows:

```
char* jsonStr = "{ \"command\" : { \"param1\": \"value1\", \"param2\": \"value2\" } }";
cJSON *jsonMsg = cJSON_Parse(jsonStr);
cJSON *command = CJSON_GetObjectItem(jsonMsg, "command");
cJSON_GetObjectItem(command,"param1")->valuestring = "new value 1";
cJSON_Delete(jsonMsg); // <— segmentation fault
```

Comment: This looks like C, not C++. Please remove the tag for the unrelated language. And your question is incomplete. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: You need to avoid editors that introduce Unicode codes `“` (U+201C) and `”` (U+201D) in lieu of `"` (U+0022); the compilers don't like them very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I first encountered this I was puzzled by the behavior.  The example is very similar to the one in the cJSON [documentation](https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON).

My first attempt at a solution was to set the ***type*** of "param1" so that the cJSON_Delete() function wouldn't try to free the memory. That is, set the "cJSON_IsReference" flag in the cJSON->type member.

The updated code was:

```
char* jsonStr = "{ \"command\" : { \"param1\": \"value1\", \"param2\": \"value2\" } }";
cJSON *jsonMsg = cJSON_Parse(jsonStr);
cJSON *command = CJSON_GetObjectItem(jsonMsg, "command");
cJSON_GetObjectItem(command,"param1")->valuestring = "new value 1";
cJSON_GetObjectItem(command,"param1")->type |= cJSON_IsReference;
cJSON_Delete(jsonMsg);
```

The final solution was to transfer the contents of the original message into a new cJSON object. This prevented a memory leak due to orphaned memory malloc'd by cJSON_Parse().

The final code looked like this:

```
char* jsonStr = "{ \"command\" : { \"param1\": \"value1\", \"param2\": \"value2\" } }";
cJSON *jsonMsg = cJSON_Parse(jsonStr);
cJSON *command = CJSON_GetObjectItem(jsonMsg, "command");

cJSON *jsonRes, *command;
jsonRes = cJSON_CreateObject();
command = cJSON_CreateObject()
cJSON_AddItemToObject(jsonRes, "command", command);
cJSON_AddStringToObject(command, cJSON_GetObjectItem(command,"param1")->string, "new value 1");
cJSON_AddItemToObject(jsonRes, "command", command = cJSON_CreateObject());
cJSON_AddStringToObject(command, 
    cJSON_GetObjectItem(command,"param2")->string, 
    cJSON_GetObjectItem(command,"param2")->valuestring);

cJSON_Print(jsonRes);

cJSON_Delete(jsonMsg);
cJSON_Delete(jsonRes);
```

Answer (score 0):

cJSON is a very nice lib, simple and neat, but one need to understand some things:

```
cJSON_GetObjectItem(command,"param1")->valuestring
```

is a `char *`, after parsing in this example.

Since you replace it with `"new value 1"`, being a `const char *`, so when deleting the `jsonMsg`, the delete command tries to free that `const char *`, resulting in a segmentation fault.

there are a couple of approaches:

```
char* jsonStr = "{ \"command\" : { \"param1\": \"value1\", \"param2\": \"value2\" } }";
cJSON *jsonMsg = cJSON_Parse(jsonStr);
cJSON *command = CJSON_GetObjectItem(jsonMsg, "command");
```

till here alright,

then one simple command:

```
cJSON_ReplaceItemInObject(command,"param1", cJSON_CreateString("new value 1"));
```

and Finish :

```
cJSON_Print(jsonMsg);
cJSON_Delete(jsonMsg);
```

**Or**

```
cJSON_DeleteItemFromObject(command,"param1");
cJSON_AddItemToObject(command,"param1",cJSON_CreateString("new value 1"));
```

**Or**

If you insist on manually manipulating, ok:

```
free(cJSON_GetObjectItem(command,"param1")->value string);
cJSON_GetObjectItem(command,"param1")->valuestring=strdup("new value 1");
```

but if you manipulate manually, one should check the `type cJSON_IsReference` before trying to free, secondly the `strdup` will allocate new memory to copy the "new value 1" in.